# Case statement in excel showing incorrect

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am wanting to do a case statement on a bit of sql that I using to see if a row is existing or not I obv changed the field names just for security but you will get jist of what i am trying to do.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN
     (SELECT table1
      FROM      table1 WITH (NOLOCK)
      WHERE   (filter1= @Product) AND (filter2= @PriceList) AND 
     (customer_code = '')) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Existing
```

But when I try it in SSME its giving me a parameter incorrect even though I am entering string product code and string for price list any body any ideas what I am doing wrong thanks. I persume will be my syntax more than anything. I dont even need the first select as I want it returned from one table ?

**Edit2**
Here is me filling in my parameters and the message display by sql server

[image]

Here is the error

[image]

Comment: Please try to explain what do you want to achieve better. Anyway few suggestions: 1) return the select statement just to see that you are getting what you are expecting to get: select (select table1 from ..), case when (....) end as existing; 2) try to use select case when exists (select 1 from table1...) instead of select case when (...) is null

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev Thanks  Yeah I did the first tested to ensure getting back what was ment to be and its fine im pritty much just wanting to return a 0 if record does not exist or a 1 if it does

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect occasion to use exists:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS 
     (SELECT 1
      FROM     table1 WITH (NOLOCK)
      WHERE   (filter1= @Product) AND (filter2= @PriceList) AND 
     (customer_code = '')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS existing
```

I suspect though that you might have problem with customer_code.  Please check the datatype - it might be numeric in which case treating it as a string is not going to work!

Try the following in a query window:

```
declare @Product varchar(10) = '13012DB'
declare @PriceList varchar(10) = 'DBD'

declare @table1 table
(
filter1 varchar(10),
filter2 varchar(10),
customer_code varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES ('Mary', 'Little', 'Lamb')

SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS 
     (SELECT 1
      FROM     @table1
      WHERE   (filter1= @Product) AND (filter2= @PriceList) AND 
     (customer_code = '')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS existing

INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES ('13012DB', 'DBD', '')

SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS 
     (SELECT 1
      FROM     @table1
      WHERE   (filter1= @Product) AND (filter2= @PriceList) AND 
     (customer_code = '')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS existing
```

It should select 0 and then 1.

Comment: i tried that its still saying that the parameter is incorrect could that be the issue i am having even though its a string john ?

Comment: What datatypes are filter1 and filter2.  Do they agree with the datatypes for @Product and @PriceList?

Comment: hi john they are both strings ?.

Comment: And the variables are also strings?  Could you give an example of the variables?

Comment: Example Product Code Would be 13012DB example Price List would be DBD

Comment: @david39ni What is the error? Could you copy and paste it?

Comment: that works fine but surly it should work from options from paramter dialog and it defeats the purpose of the query what could be going wrong

Comment: try with single quotes around the values

Comment: you should not need to do that with the parameter code i though

Comment: I thought that too - just wanted to be sure